# Extract only numbers from Word table cell into Excel cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in a word document that I need to extract only the numbers from. There are 2 cells in the document and the first one has the following string in it:

"24.00 (Hour(s))"

I just need the number "24" from that. It won't always be 2 digits since it's a duration of hours. It may be over 100. It's normally in that format "xxx.xxx" though.

The second cell I need to extract from is a bit more difficult. It looks like this:

"$125.00 to $140.00 per hour"

I would need to extract "125" and place it in a cell in excel and then extract "140" and place it in another cell. These number will always be between "$" and ".00" separated by the word "to".

The duration needs to go into column J and the rates need to be separated into column K & L.

Here is my current code:

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iTable As Integer  'table number index
Dim iRow As Long     'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer  'column index in Excel

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

Worksheets("Request Detail").Activate 'activates sheet of specific name


With wdDoc
TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
If TableNo = 0 Then
MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
"Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
End If

For iTable = 1 To TableNo

       Dim lRow As Long
       lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row + 1

        With .tables(TableNo)


            Cells(lRow - 1, "A") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(14, 2).Range.Text) 'polaris id
            Cells(lRow - 1, "B").Value = Date                                       'post current date
            Cells(lRow - 1, "C") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(16, 2).Range.Text) 'resource manager name
            Cells(lRow - 1, "D") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(15, 2).Range.Text) 'requestor name
            Cells(lRow - 1, "E") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(1, 2).Range.Text)  'customer name
            Cells(lRow - 1, "H") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(7, 2).Range.Text)  'start date
            Cells(lRow - 1, "I") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(8, 2).Range.Text)  'end date
            Cells(lRow - 1, "J") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(9, 2).Range.Text)  'duration
            Cells(lRow - 1, "K") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(12, 2).Range.Text)  'request low rate
            Cells(lRow - 1, "L") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(12, 2).Range.Text)  'request high rate


            'Cells(lRow - 1, "S") = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(3, 2).Range.Text)  need to post name of negotiatoe

        End With

Next iTable
End With

Set wdDoc = Nothing

End Sub
```

Here is an example of the table parts I'm referring to:

[image: table parts]

Comment: You could use a `Mid()` formula.  Let's say your cell A1 has "$125.00 to $140.00 per hour".  To extract the fist number `$125.00`, you can use: `=MID(A1,SEARCH("$",A1,1),SEARCH("to",A1)-2)`.  To get the "$140.00", `=MID(A1,SEARCH("$",A1,2),SEARCH("to",A1)-2)`.  Does that help?

Comment: @BruceWayne would this go into the VBA script or the Excel cell itself?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - you could use that either place. In VBA, set a variable to be that, after it's evaluated. Or you can put in the sheet directly, and refer to that cell with VBA, but I'd suggest using a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this UDF and modify to suit your need. It returns a negative one (**-1**) if there isn't a match for the N'th number in a line of text.

Assuming the text in Word cell has been put into an Excel range (say **C3**), Hours stored in column **D**, Rate min in column **E**, Rate max in column **F**, then Formulas in:
**D3**: `=GetNthNumber(C3)`
**E3**: `=GetNthNumber(C3,1)`
**F3**: `=GetNthNumber(C3,2)`

You can do more if line of text contains "days" for the Time.

```
Option Explicit

Function GetNthNumber(oItem As Variant, Optional Nth As Long) As Double
    Dim sText As String, n As Long, i As Long, oTmp As Variant
    n = Nth
    ' Set to First if argument "Nth" is not passed in
    If n <= 0 Then n = 1
    ' Retrieve the text from the input item
    Select Case TypeName(oItem)
        Case "Range":   sText = oItem.Text
        Case "String":  sText = oItem
        Case Else:      sText = CStr(oItem)
    End Select
    i = 0 ' Initialize counter
    ' Loop through all the words in the text
    For Each oTmp In Split(sText, " ")
        ' Process only if the word is a number
        If IsNumeric(oTmp) Then
            i = i + 1
            ' Check if it's the Nth number
            If i = n Then
                sText = oTmp
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ' Return -1 if there isn't an answer
    If Not IsNumeric(sText) Then sText = "-1"
    GetNthNumber = CDbl(sText)
End Function
```

---

**UPDATE**
For what you are interested in, first paste in my code above, on a new Module or bottom of your existing code, then change a few lines within the **With .tables(TableNo)** block to below:

```
Cells(lRow - 1, "J").Value = GetNthNumber(WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(9, 2).Range.Text))  'duration (Time to Book?)
Cells(lRow - 1, "K").Value = GetNthNumber(WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(12, 2).Range.Text), 1) 'request low rate
Cells(lRow - 1, "L").Value = GetNthNumber(WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(12, 2).Range.Text), 2) 'request high rate
```

Comment: Just gonna be honest, I have no clue how to implement this.

Comment: @Advancin See updates, assuming I have got the right columns from your code comments.

Comment: I tested this with some interesting values. `124 - 135` and it pulled the numbers out perfectly...crazy how well this works. Thanks again!

Comment: As long as the numbers have a space separating from other text, it will work. Please do note if it's `124 -135` (no space after the dash), the second number will be negative: `-135` You can force it to be positive by using `Abs(...)` i.e. `GetNthNumber = Abs(CDbl(sText))`